# Hover-over for a submit button: Am I doing this the best way? Is there a better way to do this?

Tags: html, css, forms

My current code is:

CSS:

```
.submitorder {
background-image: url('https://www.amleo.com/images/art/PON1.jpg');
width: 205px;
height: 52px;
font-size:0px;
}

.submitorder:hover {
background-image: url('https://www.amleo.com/images/art/PON2.jpg');
width: 205px;
height: 52px;
font-size:0px;
}
```

The HTML is simply:

```
<div><input type="submit" class="submitorder"/></div>
```

The page that I have this on is at: 
https://www.amleo.com/checkout.aspx

Should I combine the images into 1 image? How would I move what the user is seeing down to the next half of the image on hover?

Just trying to get a sense of what's good / bad / ugly. :)

Thank you.

Comment: you should definitly merge them into 1 [Tutorial to CSS Sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/), CSS is awesome for spriteing. Also you could create a very similar button with CSS if you would want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the css sprites: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

you should create something like this:

[your sprite >](http://csssprites.com/results/9129d48c10d091885b4c6cc4347db6b1/result.png)

(done with [csssprites.com/](http://csssprites.com/) )

then use:

```
.submitorder {
background-image: url('sprite.jpg');
background-position: 0px 0px;
width: 205px;
height: 52px;
font-size:0px;
}

.submitorder:hover {
background-position: 0px -62px;
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! - that seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this.

http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/